# Configuring Apache 2.2 and Tomcat 8 for a Single SSO

Tags: java, angularjs, apache, tomcat, authentication

I am currently working on a project where i have a Web Service running on a Tomcat 8 Server with Basic Authentication (DataSource Realm) configured which forms my middle layer service.
I intend to Deploy my HTML5/Angular JS based application on an Apache 2.4 Server.
This application will invoke WebServices deployed on Tomcat.

My Concern here is how can we have a session available in Apache and Tomcat both so that user does not have to login into both Servers. Also I am new to Apache so is there a way I can configure DataSource Realm in Apache like in tomcat?

Many Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, you can share Tomcat datasource realm in apache. Better solution is to use third party auth provider like OAuth/CAS and use that to provide auth services to both applications.

Comment: Thanks Sangram, But i think the Apache has Authentication and Authorization Available I am not sure how that works. I am new to OAuth can you direct me to some tutorials where i can explore that. Thanks

Comment: The [tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v) is available from Spring framework developers and uses spring security and other spring frameworks. Not sure if this fits into your requirement